# How do I change iTunes to new email address

Tags: itunes, ipad, login

I had used an answer for changing my new email address back to my old, as was suggested in a prior recommendation.  Now, the system wants to send a code to my old address in order to make the change. The problem is that I no longer have access to my old email address. As it stands, I no longer can use iTunes as it shows my old address in grey and it doesn't allow me to change it to my new address. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot gain access using the security questions, the only option you have is to [contact Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201232).